# Knockout: objects and foreach

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js, mapping

Say if I have the following object (for example, pulled from a JSON file):

```
{
   "groups": [
       {
           "name":"groupa",
           "shirts":[
               {
                   "name":"foo1", "color": "blue",  "size": "small"
               },
               {
                   "name":"foo2", "color": "green",  "size": "large"
               },
               {
                   "name":"foo3", "color": "red",  "size": "medium"
               }
           ]
       },

       {
           "name":"groupb",
           "shirts":[
               {
                   "name":"foo1", "color": "blue",  "size": "x-large"
               },
               {
                   "name":"foo2", "color": "purple",  "size": "large"
               },
               {
                   "name":"foo3", "color": "pink",  "size": "xx-large"
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

I understand how to use `observableArray`s, which contain correctly mapped data from a single object. But what if i need an `observableArray` to contain data from more than one object?

Output could be similar to below:

```
<div>
    <h2>groupa</h2>
        <h3>foo1 - large blue</h3>
        <h3>foo2 - small red</h3>

    <hr />

    <h2>groupb</h2>
        <h3>bar1 - medium purple</h3>
        <h3>bar2 - x-large white</h3>

    <hr />

    <h2>groupc</h2>
        <h3>foobar1 - large black</h3>
        <h3>foobar2 - small green</h3>
</div>
```

What I don't understand, is how to create this using one observable array?

I've tried assigning each of the `group`s to their own `observableArray`, and then the group names to another array, and then foreach the group names and then manually go through them - but that seems a mess.

What's the cleanest, most logical way?

Comment: Your data structure is very odd. Why isn't `shirts` an array? Why isn't each group an array?

Comment: I've updated the structure of the JSON (now only has two groups, purely for visual size). It was originally structured that way so I could sort based on the key of an object, rather than diving into the next level array. Let me know if that makes things easier to do what i require with Knockout (though, I doubt it?). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there was a blatantly obvious way to do this, simply map an `observableArray` against each group which contains the shirts. Like this:

```
function shirt_group_assign(item) {
    this.name = item.name;
    this.shirts = ko.observableArray([]);

    shirts_mapped = $.map(item.shirts, function(item) {
        return new shirt_assign(item);
    });

    this.shirts = shirts_mapped;
}
```

There's a working example [here](http://codepen.io/ojame/pen/wmbvj).